# Django : Resend request forms

Tags: python, django

In Django, how can I  perform a post request from template and redirect to the same template without having resend request on refresh?

I tried adding javascript to avoid reload but still, it happens

Comment: Overall, you mean how can i save form data from one page without page reloading and user will be on that page, and receive a message say for example, form has been submitted. is that you mean?

Comment: I mean I need to save the form data and come to the same page but on clicking refresh, it asks for resend request. I want to avoid the resend request on refresh.

Comment: why you want to come to the same page, if you use `ajax` to save the form with sending `csrf` token, so you will be already on same page, and which request you have to avoid on refresh?